# Highest branch thickness for a hedge trimmer

Tags: hedge

I've got something very close to [this trimmer](http://goo.gl/rmqbXq), same brand. Some branches I want to cut are 3-3.5cm thick. Will it cut those?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently not - it says in the description the gap between teeth is 16mm (1.6cm) and that indicates the thickness it will cut through. 3-3.5cm is, obviously, more than twice that thickness. You will probably find, if you use it anyway, it will 'chew' into the thicker branches, and with a bit of persistence, may eventually get them off, but leaving behind chewed up ends instead of clean cuts. These should then be 'cleaned up' by hand with a sharp pair of secateurs or loppers, cutting below the damaged area cleanly.

Comment: Such an attempt would also probably burn out the motor. Might as well start with the secateurs or loppers.